# make all number with Specified digits,python

Tags: python, python-3.x

in python, I want to get all n-digit numbers with digits 1 to n (n <10, each exactly once). How can I ??

Can similar things be done?
thanks

Comment: Please, check [ask].

Comment: Saw some good answers.  But wonder what the OP has done?  (this is prob. not a good way to help them learn?...)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `itertools.permutations()` to get the digits of each number, and then use `map()` with `str()` and `int()` to turn the generated digits into the desired numbers:

```py
import itertools

n = 3
for item in itertools.permutations(range(1, n + 1), n):
    result = int(''.join(map(str, item)))
    print(result)
```

This outputs (only first three / last three lines shown):

```py
123
132
213
231
312
321
```

Comment: OP asked for "digits 1 to n (n <10, each exactly once)" - you have given digits 1 to 9 each exactly once

Comment: The `functools.reduce` statement is unnecessary (see my answer)

Comment: Well, what if you want to perform some computation with the actual value? Your answer only works for printing the digits, and nothing else.

Comment: You still don't need `functools` - just use `int(''.join(map(str, item)))`

Comment: Sounds good. Any other suggestions?

Comment: I'm also still not sure who the downvoter is, but I'm happy to take suggestions from them for improvement as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just use `itertools.permutations`

```py
import itertools

n = 3
for item in itertools.permutations(range(1, n + 1), n):
    print(*item, sep='')
    # In case you want to do something with the integer value:
    result = int(''.join(map(str, item)))
```

Output:

```
123
132
213
231
312
321
```